# How to or should we sort "use Our::Class qw(may_be some_imports);" statements with Perl::Tidy (or not)?

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

We would like to sort `use` statements alphabetically in the beginning of our classes automatically via perltidy or maybe other tool if available. We already use `Test::PerlTidy` to test if the code is formatted before committing.

I found that Perl::Tidy has the options [`prefilter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Tidy#prefilter) and [`postfilter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Tidy#postfilter).
`prefilter` looks like the better approach, because I can sort the statements as I wish in any logical for me order, then leave it to perltidy to format it.

1. Would you recommend sorting use statements? The `use`d classes do not depend on using one before the other.
2. Would you recommend using these Perl::Tidy features?
3. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Tip: Best to leave pragmas (strict, warnings, utf8, open) where they are, or at least first.  These are conventionally all lower-case.

Comment: Personally I don't see the point in sorting `use` statements alphabetically.

Comment: If there's so many `use` statements that sorting makes sense then see [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into)

Comment: I tend to group the use statement. First core modules, then CPAN modules, finally the modules of the company.

Comment: @ikegami, Yes, we are aware of these. We use Mojolicious so this is handled already by `use Mojo::Base...` which of course will stay first.

@BarneySchmale, this is more or less our current situation.

@zdim, thanks for the hint, but for now I think we do not need it.